# Duplicate an existing app or version control on retool

Tags: retool

I have an app on retool and I want to try out some different layouts.  Is there a way to duplicate an app or have version control that you can revert to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate an app by going to the "Create New App" screen, and then instead of selecting "Blank App" you can choose "Duplicate". That'll allow you to choose an existing app to copy from.

Revision History is possible by hitting the "..." button in the top right, and then selecting "View history".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Retool updated their UI, but I wasn't able to do this with the accepted answer.

I needed to hover over the **name** of the app in the list view (before you actually edit the app) and click the ... button on the right.  Then, I selected duplicate from that dropdown.